# How do I run Ubuntu 12.04 ARM supported Edition on Oracle Virtual Box on Windows

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, arm

I have downloaded the compressed preinstalled image from `https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/OmapDesktopInstall`

The file downloaded was ubuntu-12.04-preinstalled-desktop-armhf+omap.img.gz

Its a compressed gz file and I wanted to know is it straightaway bootable like any other ubuntu iso in Virtual Box. My host system is Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, Virtualbox **does not** support hardware emulation of the ARM architecture. You may want to look at *qemu* instead, which does support software emulation (slow, but works).

Comment: Tried qemu for windows but it does not take the img file mentioned in question as valid bootable source. When I extract its a .raw file of 1.8 gb

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `qemu`, it supports arm emulation.
Therefore you'll need the additional package `qemu-kvm-extras`.

- http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/QEMU

I suggest removing `virtualbox` because `kvm` uses the same features on your native cpu for virtualization.